OMNeT++ is freezing and becoming unresponsive while running a Veins simulation
I am unable to access anything in OMNeT++ Qtenv when running a Veins simulation. I don't know the exact reason for this, but it started when I first tried to inspect a vehicle's internal communication layer and clicked somewhere on the map. Since then, it just shows this popup and becomes unresponsive.

I have tried a fresh installation of OMNeT++, both the previous version and the latest version. I also tried running a new Veins project, but the issue remains the same.

Delete .qtenvrc from the main directory of your project.
